# Highcharts-Updating charts in real time

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, highcharts

So i am trying to plot a chart that will update after every second.Currently i am fetching the data from an API and saving it in the database.Then the chart updates from there.
I am running in to issues what am i supposed to do.The chart is not updating

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Vectron;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use App\Models\Devices;
class VectronApi extends Controller
{


public function index()
{
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://vrmapi.victronenergy.com/v2/installations//overallstats',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    
  }
  ',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'X-Authorization: Bearer ', 
           'Content-Type: text/plain'
    ),
  ));
  
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  
  curl_close($curl);
  $json = json_decode($response);
     //year
    //$bs = $json->records->year->totals->bs;
    //$bv = $json->records->year->totals->bv;

    //month
    //$bv = $json->records->month->totals->bv;

    //today
    
    $bs = $json->records->today->totals->bs;
    $bv = $json->records->today->totals->bv;
    $total_solar_yield = $json->records->today->totals->total_solar_yield;
    $total_consumption = $json->records->today->totals->total_consumption;
   // $month = $json->records->month->totals->month;
   // $year = $json->records->year->totals->year;
    



    $Stats = new Devices;
    $Stats->bs= $bs;
    $Stats->bv = $bv;
    $Stats->total_consumption = $total_consumption;
    $Stats->total_solar_yield = $total_solar_yield;
    //$Stats->month= $month;
    //$Stats->year= $year;

 
    $Stats->save();




                          
    $FetchData=Devices::select(\DB::raw("avg(total_consumption) as COUNT"))
    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
    ->groupby(\DB::raw("Hour(created_at)"))
    ->pluck('COUNT');

    return view('Charts',compact('FetchData'));

  }
}
```

here is my view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Victron</title>
    <style>
        .highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 320px; 
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
  height: 400px;
}
        </style>
</head>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>Victron Overall Stats</h1>
    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container"></div>
        <p class="highcharts-description">
            Chart showing data updating every second, with old data being removed.
        </p>
    </figure>
</body>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var FetchData = <?php echo json_encode($FetchData)?>;

 
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var chart = {
               type: 'spline',
               animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in IE < IE 10.
               marginRight: 10,
               
               events: {
                  load: function () {
                     // set up the updating of the chart each second
                     var series = this.series[0];
                     
                     setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y =FetchData;
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                     }, 1000);
                  }
               }
            };
            var title = {
               text: 'Live random data'   
            };   
            var xAxis = {
               type: 'datetime',
               tickPixelInterval: 150
            };
            var yAxis = {
               title: {
                  text: 'Value'
               },
               plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#808080'
               }]
            };
            var tooltip = {
               formatter: function () {
               return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                  Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                  Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
               }
            };
            var plotOptions = {
               area: {
                  pointStart: 1940,
                  marker: {
                     enabled: false,
                     symbol: 'circle',
                     radius: 2,
                     
                     states: {
                        hover: {
                           enabled: true
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            };
            var legend = {
               enabled: false
            };
            var exporting = {
               enabled: false
            };
            var series = [{
               name: 'Consumption',
               data: (function () {
                  // generate an array of random data
                  var data = FetchData,time = (new Date()).getTime(),i;
                  
                  for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                     data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y:[FetchData]
                     });
                  }
                  return data;
               }())    
            }];     
      
            var json = {};   
            json.chart = chart; 
            json.title = title;     
            json.tooltip = tooltip;
            json.xAxis = xAxis;
            json.yAxis = yAxis; 
            json.legend = legend;  
            json.exporting = exporting;   
            json.series = series;
            json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
   
            Highcharts.setOptions({
               global: {
                  useUTC: false
               }
            });
            $('#container').highcharts(json);
         });
  
  
</script>

</html>
```

What am i not doing right?[screenshot of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mHuv.png)

Comment: Hi, The duration is unlikely to depend on Highcharts just your code. I find it hard to relate this topic to Highcharts.

Comment: Of course It will not update your chart. Because  **var FetchData = <?php echo json_encode($FetchData)?>;** does not update the latest data you get from php curl request. You need to call a ajax request to get new data then change the chart data in order to update the chart.